# how to cast a [Ljava.lang.Object that is returned by a Spring Data JPA Query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

hi i'm working in a spring mvc project using spring data jpa, i have a nativeQuey in a interface that extends from JpaRepository, in that query i select a few values from diferent tables and i return a

```
ArrayList<Object>
```

i printed the value of that ArrayList and it content this :

```
[[Ljava.lang.Object;@1f634fe, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1361a15, [Ljava.lang.Object;@1c8c51c]
```

since the query return 3 rows with 7 values for each row i suspect that those object are 3 (lists) and every list have 7 fields i'm very sure that are strings and ints, i have this two imports in my class where i watn to cast the values.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Object;
```

my question is how can i cast these list with have 3 listw inside to get my values?

this is my class that extends JpaRepository

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Object;
public interface I_GL_JE_Lines extends JpaRepository<C_GL_JE_LINES, Long>{

@Query(value ="select value1, value2, value3, value4, value5"
            + "from DB_Table, DB_Table2, DB_Table3"
            + "where id_value = 1 ", 
           nativeQuery = true)
    public ArrayList<Object> queryWithValues();
```

the method in my service class MyServiceClass.java :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Object;


public ArrayList<Object> getQueryValues() {

            ArrayList<Object> results = null;

            results = serviceAutoWiredVariable.queryWithValues();

        return results;
    }
```

and my controller class where i try to get my values

```
@Autowired MyServiceClass_autoWiredServiceClassVariable;

@RequestMapping(value = "/getVaules", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getValues(Model model) 
    {
ArrayList<Object> objectlist = null;

objectlist = _autoWiredServiceClassVariable.getQueryValues(); <--i call my method here and it return the lists that have 3 lists inside with 7 or more values each

.... HERE i want an idea how to get those values or how to cast them

 //i tried this but i gives me this exception 
//java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList


Iterator itr = objectlist .iterator();
Iterator innerIterator;
while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                ArrayList<Object> obj = (ArrayList<Object>) itr.next(); 

                innerIterator= obj.iterator();

                while(iteradorInterno.hasNext())
                {
                    Object[] innerObj = (Object[]) innerIterator.next();

                    value = String.valueOf(innerObj[0]);
                }

            }
```

this line:

```
ArrayList<Object> obj = (ArrayList<Object>) itr.next();
```

gives me this exceptio:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: Never used spring-data jpa, but shouldn't it be automatic as long as column names match bean property names? Just make that method return `List<C_GL_JE_LINES>` instead of `List<Object>`

Comment: i tried to return that but Spring data jpa dont work if you dont select all the attributes in that table and that table have like 80 attributes that i dont want to select, also i have functions like SUM() DECODE() in my original query

Answer (score 1):

An `Object[]` cannot be cast to any other type (apart from `Object`).  Period.

If you want your `Object[]` instances to be usable as lists then you need to either copy them to new `List` objects, or wrap them using `Arrays.asList()`.

---

The other approach (in theory!) would be to convince JPA to map the rows in the resultset to something other than `Object[]`.  However, my (limited) research didn't reveal a way to do that .... at least, using the Spring-data `@Query` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

What I used is explicitly defining my class type in the query itself and created parameterized constructor in the custom object that includes all the attributes I want to load from query output.

So The repository class would look like this:

```
    public interface CustomObjectDAO extends CrudRepository<CustomObject, Integer> {

        @Query("SELECT new CustomObject(obj.attribute1, obj.attribute2, 
                obj.attribute3, obj.attribute4) from CustomObject obj where 
                obj.attribute2 not in ("SELECT obj2.id FROM 
                AnotherCustomObject obj2)")
        List<CustomObject> findByCustomObject();
    }
```

Here is how CustomObject would look like:

```
public class CustomObject{
    private int attribute1;
    private String attribute2;
    private String attribute3;
    private String attribute4;

    public CustomObject(){}

    public CustomObject(int attribute1, String attribute2, String attribute3, String attribute4, String attribute5){
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
        this.attribute1 = attribute2;
        this.attribute1 = attribute3;
        this.attribute1 = attribute4;
        this.attribute1 = attribute5;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

That way it will cast list to CustomObject without any explicit casting.

Answer (score 0):

What the exception says is you are trying to convert an Object array to ArrayList. So to fix the issue you can use this line of code in your service class:

```
Object[] results = null;

results = serviceAutoWiredVariable.queryWithValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am a late comer in this thread, I hope someone else will get the benefit. I faced the same problem and lost a day while working with custom @Query.

In your case, the Exception has occurred at the iterator. What you are getting from _autoWiredServiceClassVariable.getQueryValues() is an ArrayList of Array of Objects. And you are tring to convert an array of Objects to ArrayList of Objects which causes the problem. You would be able to get the values of the query result if you modify the iteration as below.

```
Iterator itr = objectlist.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Object[] arrObj = (Object[])itr.next();
    for(Object obj:arrObj) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(obj));
    }
}
```